# Find the percentage of coin streaks

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to write a program to find out how often a streak of six heads or a streak of six tails comes up in a randomly generated list of heads and tails of 100 flips and repeat this 10000 times to find percentage of the coin flips contains a streak of six heads or tails in a row.

My code is like this, and it's some sort of working. **What I wonder is if it's giving right results: **

```
import random
numberOfStreaks = 0
# Code that creates a list of 100 'heads' or 'tails' values.
for experimentNumber in range(10000):
    results = []
    for experiment in range(100):
        x = random.randint(1, 2)
        if x == 1:
            results.append('H')
        else:
            results.append('T')
    # Code that checks if there is a streak of 6 heads or tails in a row.
    currentStreak = 0
    previousResult = results[0]

    for result in results:
        if currentStreak == 6:
            numberOfStreaks += 1
            currentStreak = 0
        if result == previousResult:
            currentStreak += 1
            previousResult = result

print('Chance of streak: %s%%' % (numberOfStreaks / 100))
```

Comment: your indentation is off, so it can't run as it is. please fix it

Comment: Sorry it was a copying problem on my side, fixed it...

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: That's the code I wrote but I'm not sure if it's giving right results. @wwii

Comment: "What I wonder is if it's giving right results" This is the constant struggle for every programmer. We have different tools for verifying the correctness of our code. Some of these include mathematical proofs and automated tests. Can you think of a way to use either of these to check your code for correctness?

Comment: How did you test it and why do you suspect it? Which part do you think is wrong?

Comment: I think this question is better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It's giving me so huge percentage, seemed odd to me but I have no other way to verify it... @wwii

Comment: @mike sorry I didn't know it existed, I'm kinda beginner...

Comment: numberOfStreaks/100 wont give you the probability of having a streak.

Comment: @retardo No worries about it, I was letting you know you might have a better chance there.

Comment: You will almost always find streaks of 6 in 100 flips, certainly more than half the time, so a large percentage shouldn't be surprising.

Comment: If you put the code that counts streaks in a function, you can *manufacture* lists with known number of streaks then test that function with those lists.

Comment: _My code is like this, and it's some sort of working. **What I wonder is if it's giving right results: **_ Is it working or is it not working? Are the results correct or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are getting a 7th repetition of heads or tails, it should be counted as a streak because the last 6 flips do form streak.  By reseting the count after 6 you are underestimating the number of streaks.

From a probability standpoint, the result you are printing is not a measure of "chance" (that would never go above 100%) but is closer to a mathematical expectancy (i.e. sum of expected values multiplied by their respective probability).  Your code produces a sampling of actual attempts but the calculations are not meaningful unless they can be compared to proper probability figures.

here's how I would implement this sampling and express the results:

```
import random
from itertools import accumulate
expCount   = 10000
expSize    = 100
streakSize = 6

numberOfStreaks = 0
for experimentNumber in range(expCount):
    results = [random.choice("HT") for _ in range(expSize)]
    consec  = [int(a==b) for a,b in zip(results,results[1:])]
    streaks = sum( s+1>=streakSize for s in accumulate(consec,lambda s,m:s*m+m))
    numberOfStreaks += streaks

ratio = numberOfStreaks / expCount
print(f'Obtained {numberOfStreaks} streaks of {streakSize} head/tail on {expCount} runs of {expSize} flips. On average {ratio:.2f} streaks per run')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
numberOfStreaks = 0
numberOfExperiments = 10000
numberOfAttemps = 100
for experimentNumber in range(numberOfExperiments):
# Code that creates a list of {numberOfAttemps} 'heads' or 'tails' values.
    coinFlip = []
    for i in range(numberOfAttemps):
            if random.randint(0, 1) == 0:
                coinFlip.append("H")
            else:
                coinFlip.append("T")
# Code that checks if there is a streak of 6 heads or tails in a row.
    for i in range(len(coinFlip)):
        if (["H"] * 6) in [coinFlip[i:i+6]] or (["T"] * 6) in [coinFlip[i:i+6]]:
            numberOfStreaks += 1
            for n in range(5):
                coinFlip.pop(i)
print('Chance of streak: %s%%' % (numberOfStreaks / numberOfExperiments))
```

Output:

```
Chance of streak: 1.5143%
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to divide the number of streaks you got by the number of possible streaks in the 10000 experiments, that's the probability of having a streak I believe.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you're counting how many streaks you have *overall* in each set of results and then just printing that divided by 100. That's not quite what you meant to find.

You want to check how many *experiments* contain a streak of 6 or higher.

Here's my jab at it.

First of all, let's set up the experiment.

```py
import random

number_of_flips = 100
number_of_experiments = 10000
streak_length = 6
streaks = 0
```

It's always good to set these beforehand so that you may change them when tweaking things.

```py
for experiment in range(number_of_experiments):
    # We want number_of_flips random values of 0 and 1 
    # (0 - head, 1 tails)
    flips = [random.randint(0, 1) for _ in range(number_of_flips)]

    # Now we want to see if we find any streaks of streak_length
    heads_streak = 0
    tails_streak = 0

    for i in flips:

      if i == 0:
        heads_streak += 1
        tails_streak = 0
        if heads_streak >= streak_length:
          streaks += 1
          break

      if i == 1:
        heads_streak = 0
        tails_streak += 1
        if tails_streak >= streak_length:
          streaks += 1
          break

    # At this point, if we found a streak, streaks grew by 1,
    # and if not, it remains unchanged
```

Now we have the number of experiments where we found streaks in `streaks`.

And we can find that by dividing it by the number of experiments and multiplying it by 100.

`print(streaks / number_of_experiments * 100, "%")`

Answer (score 0):

```
import random, time
numberOfStreaks = 0
for experimentNumber in range(10000):
    # Code that creates a list of 100 'heads' or 'tails' values.
    List = []
    for value in range(100):
        value = random.randint(0,1)
        if value == 0:
            List.append('H')
        if value == 1:
            List.append('T')
    # print('List = ', end=' ')
    # print(List)
    # Code that checks if there is a streak of 6 heads or tails in a row.
    sixStreakHeads = 0
    sixStreakTails = 0
    for result in range(len(List)):
        if List[result] == 'H':
            sixStreakHeads += 1
            sixStreakTails = 0
            if sixStreakHeads == 6:
                sixStreakHeads = 0
                numberOfStreaks += 1
        if List[result] == 'T':
            sixStreakTails += 1
            sixStreakHeads = 0
            if sixStreakTails == 6:
                sixStreakTails = 0
                numberOfStreaks += 1
    # print('Six Streak Heads: ', sixStreakHeads)
    # print('Six Streak Tails: ', sixStreakTails)
    # time.sleep(.5)
    # print('\n\n\n')
print('Chance of streak: ', numberOfStreaks / 10000 * 100, '%')
```

Comment: thanks for contributing an answer, can you add some explanation to it?